# Jersey resources hyperlinks

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I'm implementing a RESTful web service and I want to make my resources linked together with hyperlink. In practice I want to include in my json responses fields with links to other resources.
What's the best way to achieve that with jersey rest framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know, Jersey's support for hypermedia links is still "work in progress" and even changed in between versions (1.x - 2.x). You can search for "declarative hyperlinking".

Some resources to read: [Declarative Hyperlinking by Example (Jersey)](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/pages/DeclarativeHyperlinkingInJersey) with the [accompanying sample](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/samples/jersey-server-linking-sample/) and the documentation for [Jersey 1.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/linking.html) and [Jersey 2.x](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/declarative-linking.html).

Hope it helps!